# Which text editor for aFrame

Tags: aframe

somebody know which texteditor I can use for an Aframe project?

Until know I use Brackets and with the live prewiev is very good, but I read that Brackets stop Support until September this year.

So for the future I am looking for an alternative to brackets.
Some suggestions?

Comment: A-Frame is just HTML and Javascript. Any text editor should work fine: vi, emacs, sublime, vscode… Just personal preference.

Comment: You can use any text editor as stated in the comment above. Even a browser-based one like https://glitch.com/ that offers a live preview, that works with A-Frame. I personally use VS code with node.js live server

Comment: Thank for the answer. I use Brackets because I have an Live Preview Mode. If I use other text editors I have to run an local Server like Xampp ecc.... May I should ask, which text editor offers an live preview mode??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find a good alternative. I will use Visual Studio Code now. The have an Brackets Extensions and a live server prewiev, so that what I was looking for..